# PHP form action and method into Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

It is possible to transfer my php form action and method process into jquery process?

I tried to insert input data into database using php form action and method and it is working but in jquery process nothing happen.

```
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="submit" id="signUpButton" value="Sign Up">
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signUpButton").click(function(){
        $.post("signUpAction.php", function(data, status){
           alert("data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: share complete code dont' remove action and method from html ? share actual html and `.php` file also ?

Comment: You're not sending anything with this post request. Try adding your form data by serializing it like : `$.post("signUpAction.php", $("form").serialize(), function(data, status){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the form data as well. It can be done by jQuery serialize method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signUpButton").click(function(){
        $.post("signUpAction.php", $("form").serialize(), function(data, status){ 
            alert("data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp) to send data to PHP file and using [serializeArray()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp) to get your form data and store it in a variable that will send to PHP file.

Try like this

> Your HTML

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value=''/>
  <input type="email" name="email" value=''/>
</form>
```

> Your js should be like this:

```
 $('#add_new_stu').click(function(event) {
    var formdata= $("form").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "file.php",  
        data: formdata,  
        success: function(response){
                console.log(response);  
            }
    });
});
```

> With PHP you should loop your result array.

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
//do some thing here
```